# Fancybox jQuery, simple error probably

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm a newbie at jquery, among other things, so I apologize for the ignorance. I can't figure out why this script isn't affecting anything. I click on the thumbnail, and I get a new page with the full image, no fancybox. I checked the script links (not shown here) and they appear correct, so I'm thinking that this code must not be valid somehow. The funny thing is it all worked with an earlier version of FancyBox. Help please, and let me know if more info is required to give an answer. Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("a.projectgallery").fancybox({
            'transitionIn'      : 'fade',
            'transitionOut'     : 'fade',
            'titlePosition'     : 'over',
            'titleShow'     : 'true',
            'overlayShow'       : 'true',
            'overlayColor'      : '#fff',
            'overlayOpacity'    : '0.9',
            'showNavArrows'     : 'true',
            'enableEscapeButton'    : 'true',
            'scrolling'     : 'no',
            'onStart':function(currentArray,currentIndex,currentOpts){
                var obj = currentArray[ currentIndex ];
                if ($(obj).next().length)
                this.title = $(obj).next().html();},
            'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
                return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">' + title + '</span>';
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: If you use Firebug, click Persist and check in it so see if you are getting any errors

Comment: $("a.projectgallery").fancybox is not a function
[Break On This Error] 'titleFormat' : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {

Comment: But how is titleFormat not a function? According to http://fancybox.net/api it is. ?

Comment: What order are you loading the scripts?

Comment: No. And the other scripts (localScroll) are working.

Comment: Did you forget to include fancy box in the head of the page?

Comment: I reproduced a similar error by loading your code into a jsfiddle page without adding the code for fancybox. Error: $("a.projectgallery").fancybox is not a function
Source File: http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/
Line: 38

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=2.0.3"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=2.0.3"></script>

Comment: And you're loading jQuery itself before all of those?

Comment: Load jQuery first, it provides the base that all of those other libraries sit on top of.

Comment: <!-- javascript -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- fancybox plugin --> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=2.0.3"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=2.0.3"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

Comment: i'm pretty sure i am loading jquery first, it comes before the fancybox script in the head.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And so, once again, I'm shown that the simplest and most obvious solution is usually the best one ...

My links were incorrect:

This ...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
```

should have been this ...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
```

Thanks for helping, guys. Sorry for the stupidity and wasting your time.

Comment: No problem, @4rederick. You can accept this as the answer to your question in case others run across this.

Answer (score 0):

Try separating functions:

```
function formatTitle(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
    return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">' + title + '</span>';
}
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("a.projectgallery").fancybox({
            'transitionIn'      : 'fade',
            'transitionOut'     : 'fade',
            'titlePosition'     : 'over',
            'titleShow'     : 'true',
            'overlayShow'       : 'true',
            'overlayColor'      : '#fff',
            'overlayOpacity'    : '0.9',
            'showNavArrows'     : 'true',
            'enableEscapeButton'    : 'true',
            'scrolling'     : 'no',
            'titleFormat'       : formatTitle
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

All Boolean or integer values should be set without quotes so `'overlayShow': 'true'` should be `'overlayShow': true` and `'overlayOpacity' : '0.9'` should be `'overlayOpacity' : 0.9` .

Comment: thanks for the correction. i fixed it. still doesn't solve my problem though unfortunately.

Comment: would be interesting to see a link with your issue. We could help you faster and better. Otherwise we would be just guessing.

Comment: so flippin' weird. i uploaded it and now it seems to be working (well, the custom function isn't working, and the css needs tweaked).  www.josephfrederick.com

Comment: Not working really well. You are using API options from ver 1.3.x that are not compatible with ver 2.x. Check the documentation for the version you are using http://fancyapps.com/fancybox#docs

Comment: I'll go back and start from scratch with it then. Probably the best way. I still don't know why it isn't working local. Could it be because the API options are not correct?